# How do I replace multiple <br/> tags with a specific element in a new line?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I have a XML file that contains multiple `<p>` tags in it. Some of the `<p>` tags contain `<br/>` in it. So, I am supposed to create a new `XElement` for each `<br/>` in the tag. I have tried to achieve by reading each line using `foreach` and replacing each `<br/>` with `</p> + Environment.NewLine + <p>`.

It works but if `<p>` contains tags like `<b>` or `<i>`, then `<` and `>` become `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively. Which is why, I want a `linq` approach or a `foreach` approach, so that I am able to do the changes while in XML format.

Plase help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE repub SYSTEM "C:\repub\Repub_V1.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet href="C:\repub\repub.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<repub>
<head>
<title>xxx</title>
</head>
<body>
<sec>
<title>First Title</title>
<break name="1-1"/>
<pps>This is Sparta</pps>
<h1><page num="1"/>First Heading</h1>
<bl>This is another text</bl>
<fig><img src="images/img_1-1.jpg" alt=""/><fc>This is a caption</fc></fig>
<p>This is a sentence<br/> that will be broken down <br/>into separate paragraph tags.</p>
</break>
</sec>
</body>
</repub>
```

What I want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE repub SYSTEM "C:\repub\Repub_V1.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet href="C:\repub\repub.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<repub>
<head>
<title>xxx</title>
</head>
<body>
<sec>
<title>First Title</title>
<break name="1-1"/>
<pps>This is Sparta</pps>
<h1><page num="1"/>First Heading</h1>
<bl>This is another text</bl>
<fig><img src="images/img_1-1.jpg" alt=""/><fc>This is a caption</fc></fig>
<p>This is a sentence</p>
<p>that will be broken down</p>
<p>into separate paragraph tags.</p>
</break>
</sec>
</body>
</repub>
```

What I tried:

```
List<XElement> brs = xdoc.Descendants("br").ToList();
for (int i = brs.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    brs[i].ReplaceWith(new XElement("br", new XElement("p", new object[] {brs[i].Attributes(), brs[i].Nodes()})));
}
```

I got this code from StackOverflow itslef in one of my older questions.

What I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE repub SYSTEM "C:\repub\Repub_V1.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet href="C:\repub\repub.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<repub>
<head>
<title>xxx</title>
</head>
<body>
<sec>
<title>First Title</title>
<break name="1-1"/>
<pps>This is Sparta</pps>
<h1><page num="1"/>First Heading</h1>
<bl>This is another text</bl>
<fig><img src="images/img_1-1.jpg" alt=""/><fc>This is a caption</fc></fig>
<p>This is a sentence<br><p/></br> that will be broken down <br><p/></br>into separate paragraph tags.</p>
</break>
</sec>
</body>
</repub>
```

Comment: Have you considered using Regex to replace the line breaks with paragraph tags?

Comment: Using Regex for this kind of thing is normally a very bad idea because XML is not a regular language.

Comment: Any suggestions? I am stuck in this step for a couple of days now.

Comment: I just answered.

Comment: My original solution worked : for (int i = brs.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                brs[i].ReplaceWith(new XElement("p", new object[] { brs[i].Attributes(), brs[i].Nodes() }));
            }

Comment: @jdweng - Actually it did not, the output was like I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: No.  That was my second answer when you didn't like the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the best answer but it will do most of what you want:

```
List<XElement> p = xdoc.Descendants("p").ToList();
for (int i = p.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var newP = new XElement("p");
    newP.ReplaceAttributes(p[i].Attributes());

    foreach (var node in p.Nodes())
    {
        if (node.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element && ((XElement)node).Name == "br")
        {
            p[i].AddBeforeSelf(newP);
            newP = new XElement("p");
            newP.ReplaceAttributes(p[i].Attributes());
        }
        else
        {
            newP.Add(node);
        }
    }
    p[i].AddBeforeSelf(newP);
    p[i].Remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to try a different approach to see if it would work … by leveraging Regular Expressions.  It isn't as elegant as using XML document, but it was fun to try out.

```
void Main()
{
    string info = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
    <!DOCTYPE repub SYSTEM ""C:\repub\Repub_V1.dtd"">
    <?xml-stylesheet href=""C:\repub\repub.xsl"" type=""text/xsl""?>
    <repub>
    <head>
    <title>xxx</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <sec>
    <title>First Title</title>
    <break name=""1-1""/>
    <pps>This is Sparta</pps>
    <h1><page num=""1""/>First Heading</h1>
    <bl>This is another text</bl>
    <fig><img src=""images/img_1-1.jpg"" alt=""""/><fc>This is a caption</fc></fig>
    <p>This is a sentence<br/> that will be broken down <br/>into separate paragraph tags.</p>
    </break>
    </sec>
    </body>
    </repub>";

    string result = null;
    try
    {
        Regex regexObj = new Regex("<p>(.*?)</p>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
        result = regexObj.Replace(info, new MatchEvaluator(ConvertBR));
        result.Dump();
    }
    catch (ArgumentException ex)
    {
        // Syntax error in the regular expression
    }
}

public String ConvertBR(Match m)
{
    return m.Value.Replace("<br/>","</p><p>");
}
```